# Data is not written into the XML file from mongodb using Spring Batch, Why?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am developing Spring Batch MongoDB to XML example. I was successfully developed the application, but I dont see data is getting written into the XML file. Could you please guide me what is the issue ? I dont see any working example yet on the web.

**job-report.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <!-- Actual Job -->
    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="mongodbItemReader" writer="xmlItemWriter" commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="mongodbItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader">
        <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <property name="collection" value="report" />
        <property name="targetType" value="com.mkyong.model.Report" />
        <property name="query" value="{'_id':{$gt:0} }" />
        <property name="sort">
            <util:map>
                 <entry key="id" value="#{T(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction).ASC}" /> 
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/report.xml" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="reportUnMarshaller" />
        <property name="rootTagName" value="record" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="reportUnMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <value>com.mkyong.model.Report</value>
        </property>
   </bean> 
</beans>
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] springConfig = { "database.xml", "context.xml", "job-report.xml" };

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

**Logs from console:**

```
14:58:52.487 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.c.StepContextRepeatCallback - Preparing chunk execution for StepContext: org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext@aa594b
14:58:52.487 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.c.StepContextRepeatCallback - Chunk execution starting: queue size=0
14:58:52.487 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
14:58:52.487 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Starting repeat context.
14:58:52.487 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat operation about to start at count=1
14:58:52.488 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query: { "_id" : { "$gt" : 0}} fields: null for class: class com.mkyong.model.Report in collection: report
14:58:52.488 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[yourdb]
14:58:52.488 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Registering Spring transaction synchronization for MongoDB instance yourdb.
14:58:52.488 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.query - Sending query of namespace yourdb.report on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:53}] to server 127.0.0.1:27017
14:58:52.489 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.query - Query completed
14:58:52.489 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
14:58:52.489 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet - Inputs not busy, ended: true
14:58:52.489 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
14:58:52.489 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
14:58:52.490 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=1, version=5, name=step1, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=4, filterCount=0, writeCount=4 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=5, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
14:58:52.490 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
14:58:52.491 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
14:58:52.491 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@a8ee09]
14:58:52.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
14:58:52.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Step execution success: id=1
14:58:52.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
14:58:52.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
14:58:52.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@5b3037]
14:58:52.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
14:58:52.494 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
14:58:52.494 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@baa89c]
14:58:52.495 [main] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=1, version=7, name=step1, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=4, filterCount=0, writeCount=4 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=5, rollbackCount=0
14:58:52.495 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
14:58:52.496 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
14:58:52.496 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@1f2ebae]
14:58:52.496 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Completed state=reportJob.step1 with status=COMPLETED
14:58:52.496 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Handling state=reportJob.end1
14:58:52.496 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Completed state=reportJob.end1 with status=COMPLETED
14:58:52.497 [main] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=0, version=1, startTime=Tue Jan 10 14:58:52 IST 2017, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Tue Jan 10 14:58:52 IST 2017, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=0, version=0, Job=[reportJob]], jobParameters=[{}]
14:58:52.497 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
14:58:52.501 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
14:58:52.501 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@498b0]
14:58:52.501 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=reportJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
Exit Status : COMPLETED
Done
```

In this example, I do need to manually create xml/report.xml into the classpath. Ideally it should be automatic. Right?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem from the link: [Complex XML using Spring Batch; StaxEventItemWriter ; Jaxb2Marshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129185/complex-xml-using-spring-batch-staxeventitemwriter-jaxb2marshaller). Also I should use

```
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:outputs/report.xml" />
        <property name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
        <property name="version" value="1.0" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
        <property name="rootTagName" value="record" />
    </bean>
```