# How can I fetch data from multiple tables and place it in an XML file using Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, shell, spring-batch

I have been trying to fetch details from multiple tables in a database and provide the output in the form of XML file using Spring batch. Is there any working code to do the above task or any idea to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following links should guide you.

If simple then xml then:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-mysql-database-to-xml/

For complex xml using spring, refer to these threads;
[Complex XML using Spring Batch; StaxEventItemWriter ; Jaxb2Marshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129185/complex-xml-using-spring-batch-staxeventitemwriter-jaxb2marshaller)

[Build non trivial XML file with StaxEventItemWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678901/build-non-trivial-xml-file-with-staxeventitemwriter)